# Is there any way to retain the entered customer billing/shipping addresses in magento admin once entered?

Tags: product, adminhtml, magento2.2.6, order-grid, customer-address

We see that the addresses of billing/shipping added to the order creation process gets erased if we remove all line items from the cart and then add back new product using "Add products by SKU" button.

This feature is only on the enterprise edition of Magento 2.2.6

Can anyone guide us on this?